# Уведомления у комментариев у вопросов

Tags: предложение

Такая ситуация, новичок спрашивает вопрос, в вопросе недостаточно данных и я пишу комментарий к вопросу с уточняющим вопросом.

Новичёк отвечает на комментарий, но не ставит в комментарии @МоёИмя, так как он новичёк и не знает как работает движок SO.

И я никакого уведомления об ответе на комментарий не получаю...

В результате связь общения меня и того кто задал вопрос теряется.

Что приходится делать - держать открытыми такие вопросы в браузере и регулярно чекать не появился ли ответ к комментарию, это напрягает и тратит кучу времени.

Comment: Если комментатор только один под сообщением, то ник не требуется для уведомления.

Comment: Видимо я попадал на ситуации когда комментаторов было больше.

Comment: и кому тогда должны прийти уведомления по Вашему мнению? Всем?

Comment: Всё же вопрос текущий это не [дефект], а скорее [предложение]. Только пока недостаточно понятное. А может это должна быть вовсе [поддержка] или [обсуждение]?

Comment: решения я не знаю, просто написал то что напрягает, а какой меткой отметить, не возражаю если поправите, тут много вариантов есть

Comment: как одно из решений это возможность помечать вопрос как подписано что бы получать все комменты, но думаю это делать никто не будет, так что можно и не предлагать

Comment: тогда это больше смахивает на [meta-tag:нытьё] :)

Comment: как вариант при определённых условиях показывать автору вопроса подсказку о необходимости вставить имя в сообщение.

Comment: если есть разные люди в обсуждении то показывать подсказку по поводу необходимости (если автор хочет что бы сообщение дошло адресату) указать имя адресата.

Comment: Насколько помню,  на ХК в таком случае приходило оповещение. Видимо всем комментаторам.

Comment: А еще можно было бы сделать кнопку «ответ», такой функционал есть в приложении для мобильных платформ. Ну и на сайт есть [предложение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4798/339911) отклонённое. Там и юзерскрипт можно взять (сам не проверял).

Comment: `Если комментатор только один под сообщением, то ник не требуется для уведомления.` @alexolut не требуется для автора вопроса, для обычного участника - требуется.

Comment: @FoggyFinder может быть, но мы же об авторе (которой новичок) и говорим.